# How to evaluate this double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $C$ be the subset of the plane given by $$C \colon= \{ \ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | -1 \leq x = y \leq 1 \}. $$

Then how to evaluate the double integral
$$ \int_C \int (x^2+ y^2) dx dy? $$

My work:

Since $x = y$ for all $(x,y) \in C$, we can write 
$$  \int_C \int (x^2+ y^2) dx dy = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} (x^2 + x^2) dx dx = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} 2x^2 dx dx = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{4}{3} dx = \frac{8}{3}. $$ Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure that should be an equals sign in the domain?  Double integration of a line segment is volume under an area-measure of $0$. $\\ \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{x}^{x} (x^2+y^2) \operatorname{d}y \operatorname{d}x = 0$

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: How to get this answer using the iterated integrals?

Comment: Have you plotted your region to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $C$ is exactly as you gave it, then your solution is incorrect, since $C$ is just the diagonal of the square with sides from $-1$ to $1$ and the integral is zero. Integrating in $R^2$ over a line segment is the same as integrating in $R$ over a point. The integrals are a way to understand what area is. The area of a point in a line is zero, and the area of a line in the plane is also zero. Informally it is the difference between meters and square meters.

In your case, to find the limits of integration, you can think that since $x=y$, we have that $x$ goes from $y$ to $y$ and $y$ from $-1$ to $1$. So you would have 
$$ \int_{-1}^1\int_y^yf(x,y)dxdy=\int_{-1}^10dy=0$$

Comment: Can you please try to do it using the technique of iterated integrals?

Comment: Done, fixed my reply above.

Answer (score 0):

Let $1_{C}$ denote the characteristic function of set $C$. And define $f\left(x,y\right)=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)1_{C}\left(x,y\right)$

Then: $$\underset{C}{\iint}x^{2}+y^{2}dxdy=\iint f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$$

Now fix $y$ and have a look at function $g_{y}\left(x\right)=f\left(x,y\right)$.

It is prescribed by $x\mapsto0$ if $x\neq y$ and $x\mapsto2y^{2}$
otherwise.

Then clearly $\int g_{y}\left(x\right)dx=0$ for each $y$
and consequently: $$\iint f\left(x,y\right)dxdy=\int\int g_{y}\left(x\right)dxdy=\int0dy=0$$